# Define() (PHP) Alternative for ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, .net

Is there an alternative to `define("BASE_PATH", "http://localhost");` for PHP in ASP.NET C#?

I've been searching online for hours, yet most results give me 'definitions' of asp.net, or php, or alternative (lol?).

Thank you

Comment: don't understand fully, do you want to define a constant in PHP, or C#?

Comment: Well, like, I know what a Constant is in C#, but I thought that define(string, string) in PHP was a totally different thing, @MattK

Comment: nope, same thing. [define — Defines a named constant.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the same thing:

```
const string BASE_PATH = "http://localhost";
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a static or a constant of appropriate visibility to the use in question.

For a base path, `Request.ApplicationPath` may be more useful than something hard-coded.

Comment: Thank you, @JonH, I will see how Request.ApplicationPath goes.

Comment: Note that it includes the `/` if it's the root of the URI but not the final `/` if it's an application within the root. This makes sense when you consider how IIS defines things, but is a nuisance in practice most of the time. I tend to set a static to `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath == "/" ? "" : HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath` and use that.

Answer (score 1):

`define` is a constant assignment in `PHP`. Since ASP.NET is object-oriented language you assingn constants something like

```
class YourCSharpClass{
    const string ConstName = <value>;
}
```

But I think you assign some special meaning to those `BASE_PATH` variable. Are you using Windows.Forms or ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen this before but looking it up it seems like this definition is only used for prepanding a a url? Do you need to do this can't you make everything relative?

Alterantively you could probably use the AppSettings.